# Memory leak, but CGContextRelease destroys view

Tags: ios, memory, drawrect

I'm facing a memory issue:

Using a custom Background.m class, I'm creating gradient backgrounds based on a selection of colours being passed to the class. The problem arises in that there seems to be leak, nothing exciting, but builds up over time. Releasing the context in drawRect removes the memory issue, but then there's no gradient being drawn. What's the best solution / work around? Use Apple's gradients?  Here's the code passed to the drawRect method of the Background class:

```
    //1. create vars
    float increment = 1.0f / (colours.count-1);
    CGFloat * locations = (CGFloat *)malloc((int)colours.count*sizeof(CGFloat));
    CFMutableArrayRef mref = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    //2. go through the colours, creating cgColors and locations
    for (int n = 0; n < colours.count; n++){
        CFArrayAppendValue(mref, (id)[colours[n] CGColor]);
        locations[n]=(n*increment);
    }

    //3. create gradient
    CGContextRef ref = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef spaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColors(spaceRef, mref, locations);

    if (isHorizontal){
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ref, gradientRef, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, 0.0), kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    } else if (isDiagonal) {
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ref, gradientRef, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    } else {
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ref, gradientRef, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), CGPointMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height), kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    }

    CGContextRelease(ref); //ISSUE
    CGColorSpaceRelease(spaceRef);
    CGGradientRelease(gradientRef);
```

Comment: You don’t own ref. You borrowed one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Create`, `Copy`, and `Retain` must be balanced by a `Release`. You're violating that twice here.

First, you have no balancing `Release` for `CFArrayCreateMutable`.

Second, you're releasing something you don't own (`ref`).

Related, every `malloc` must be balanced by a `free`, so you're leaking `locations`.

Your cleanup code should be

```
free(locations);
CGRelease(mref);
CGColorSpaceRelease(spaceRef);
CGGradientRelease(gradientRef);
```

Comment: @E.Coms Thanks. Fixed.